# Gamecenter sandbox: I want to disable the automatch players from gamecenter in ios6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, game-center

i am creating a game using gamecenter Now Its a turn based game and i am inviting the players for the match. The minimum no is 2 and maximum is 7. It works fine in ios5 but when I run the app in ios6 i invite only 2 players but it automatches upto 7 players in sanbox.

The method for inviting players is not deprecated and it is below:

```
- (void)findMatchWithMinPlayers:(int)minPlayers maxPlayers:(int)maxPlayers viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;               

    presentingViewController = viewController;

    GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init]; 
    request.minPlayers = 2;     
    request.maxPlayers = 7;
}
```

How to restrict the number of players to the invited players only and not automatch players. How will i get this?

Answer (score 0):

The code is not sufficient to get idea.

But i am giving you the idea logically that you want min 2 player and max 7 player.

Then you should use condition like -> min >=2 and max <= 7 and then selection of player ll be inside that condition.

So you ll get the player min 2 and max 7.

Is it okay ?